# Apple TV 3 and H264 MKV playback?

Tags: appletv

I am debating on purchasing the WD LIVE or Apple TV 3. And I wanted to know if it is possible that the ATV can do .mkv and .avi playback on non-itunes media. (i.e. pulling it from my server)

Answer (score 3):

AppleTV does not have native support for mkv files. You can use various third-party programs to transcode and send to AppleTV, ranging from the simple ([Beamer](http://beamer-app.com/)) to the full library solutions ([Plex](http://plex.tv) combined with PlexConnect).

Comment: An alternative to beamer for Windows is PopCast (http://www.popcastapp.com/). 
Disclosure: I am Co-Founder of PopCast.